# How to make all these swing controls to have the same width?

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager

I'd like the Data, View and Formatting group to have the same width as *Motion controls*. I tried `setMinimumSize(new Dimension(250,30))` but it has no effect.

[image]

```
class DeeLiteControlPanel extends JPanel
{
    public DeeLiteControlPanel()
    {
        setBounds(0, 140, 250, 550);
        JPanel dataGroup = createGroupWithName("Data");

        add(dataGroup);

        JButton loadBtn = new JButton("Load data");
        dataGroup.add(loadBtn);

        JPanel viewGroup = createGroupWithName("View");
        viewGroup.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        add(viewGroup);

        JButton skyBtn = new JButton("View from sky");
        viewGroup.add(skyBtn, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        final JToggleButton chaseBtn = new JToggleButton("Chase Vehicle");
        viewGroup.add(chaseBtn, BorderLayout.EAST);

        _vehicleList = new JComboBox();
        _vehicleList.setEditable(false);
        viewGroup.add(_vehicleList, BorderLayout.WEST);

        JButton fitToWinBtn = new JButton("Fit to Window");
        viewGroup.add(fitToWinBtn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JPanel formattingGroup = createGroupWithName("Formatting");
        formattingGroup.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(250, 20));
        formattingGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 0));
        add(formattingGroup);

        final JCheckBox showSurface = new JCheckBox("Show surface");
        showSurface.setSelected(true);
        formattingGroup.add(showSurface);

        final JCheckBox showTerrain = new JCheckBox("Show terrain");
        showTerrain.setSelected(true);
        formattingGroup.add(showTerrain);

        final JCheckBox showVehicleStatus = new JCheckBox("Show vehicle status");
        showVehicleStatus.setSelected(true);
        formattingGroup.add(showVehicleStatus);

        JPanel pnl = createGroupWithName("Depth Stretch");
        formattingGroup.add(pnl);
        JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 10);
        pnl.add(slider);
    }

    public static JPanel createGroupWithName(String name)
    {
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
        pnl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), name));
        pnl.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(250, 30));
        return pnl;
    }
}
```

Comment: get rid of all `setBounds()`. Use a BoxLayout for the overall layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to the `DeeLiteControlPanel` or call `setPreferredSize()` method for all panels - Data, View and Formatting.

```
class DeeLiteControlPanel extends JPanel
{
    public DeeLiteControlPanel()
    {
      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints gs=new GridBagConstraints();

      gs.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
      gs.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH; //or HORIZONTAL

      gs.gridx=0;
      gs.gridy=0;
      add(dataGroup,gs);

      gs.gridx=0;
      gs.gridy=1;
      add(viewGroup,gs);
      ....
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Get rid of all use of `setBounds(...)` and consider using a BoxLayout for the main JPanel:

```
public DeeLiteControlPanel() {
   // setBounds(0, 140, 250, 550);
   setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DeeLiteControlPanel extends JPanel {
   public DeeLiteControlPanel() {
      // setBounds(0, 140, 250, 550);
      setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

      JPanel dataGroup = createGroupWithName("Data");


      add(dataGroup);

      JButton loadBtn = new JButton("Load data");
      dataGroup.add(loadBtn);

      JPanel viewGroup = createGroupWithName("View");
      viewGroup.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
      add(viewGroup);

      JButton skyBtn = new JButton("View from sky");
      viewGroup.add(skyBtn, BorderLayout.NORTH);

      final JToggleButton chaseBtn = new JToggleButton("Chase Vehicle");
      viewGroup.add(chaseBtn, BorderLayout.EAST);

      JComboBox _vehicleList = new JComboBox();
      _vehicleList.setEditable(false);
      viewGroup.add(_vehicleList, BorderLayout.WEST);

      JButton fitToWinBtn = new JButton("Fit to Window");
      viewGroup.add(fitToWinBtn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      JPanel formattingGroup = createGroupWithName("Formatting");
      formattingGroup.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(250, 20));
      formattingGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 0));
      add(formattingGroup);

      final JCheckBox showSurface = new JCheckBox("Show surface");
      showSurface.setSelected(true);
      formattingGroup.add(showSurface);

      final JCheckBox showTerrain = new JCheckBox("Show terrain");
      showTerrain.setSelected(true);
      formattingGroup.add(showTerrain);

      final JCheckBox showVehicleStatus = new JCheckBox("Show vehicle status");
      showVehicleStatus.setSelected(true);
      formattingGroup.add(showVehicleStatus);

      JPanel pnl = createGroupWithName("Depth Stretch");
      formattingGroup.add(pnl);
      JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 10);
      pnl.add(slider);
   }

   public static JPanel createGroupWithName(String name) {
      JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
      pnl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
            BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), name));
      pnl.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(250, 30));
      return pnl;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      DeeLiteControlPanel mainPanel = new DeeLiteControlPanel();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("DeeliteControlPanel");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are up to it, you can use the powerful GroupLayout. it works perfect and gives you so much control on the sizes of the components and how you can tie their sizes together. mostly though i let Netbeans take care of all that.